# can not find client Secret on google OAUTH2

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth

I am trying to read a worksheet from my google drive, so after a lot of searching and reading (and importing jar files) i managed to get [this](http://soatutorials.blogspot.co.at/2013/08/google-spreadsheet-api-connecting-with.html) without any errors. The problem is that i cant get the `client Secret` that i need. Everybody on the web says that it is on the json file or at the google's developer console when i created the id, but it is not. 
My json file is like this

```
{
  "private_key_id": ".....",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----......\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "xxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "xxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "type": "service_account"
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I had to choose `Installed Application` instead of `Service Account`. With that option the client secret was created.